# parsing the array of objects in JSON and converting it to flat JSON using JOLT transform

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

My input looks like the below;

```
{
  "family": [
    {
      "person": {
        "personId": {
          "value": "12345"
        },
        "employeeAuthCd": {
          "code": "AUTH_12345"
        },
        "employeeTypeCd": {
          "code": "cd"
        },
        "status": {
          "code": "New"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired Output

```
{
  "Person_ID":"12345",
  "employeeAuthCd":"AUTH_1345",
  "employeeTypeCd":"cd",
  "status":"New"
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the `Jolt spec`, I have tried many possible specs but couldn't reach the desired output, like the above, `JSON` have multiple array of objects those I need to convert those into flat `JSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This spec should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "family": {
        "*": {
          "person": {
            "personId": {
              "value": "Person_ID"
            },
            "employeeAuthCd": {
              "code": "employeeAuthCd"
            },
            "employeeTypeCd": {
              "code": "employeeTypeCd"
            },
            "status": {
              "code": "status"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```